# Questions on building RSS feed

Tags: rss, feed, rss2

I am building RSS feed for the first time and I have some simple, direct questions that I was unable to find on the web, well at list in a sense that would be clear to me. Can you help me understand following

- Which items should I include in RSS generation? should I always put in all the articles or what is the criteria when I query my articles for the feed?
- What value should I set for `pubDate`? The specification says *"The publication date for the content in the channel. For example, the New York Times publishes on a daily basis, the publication date flips once every 24 hours. That's when the pubDate of the channel changes."*. I do not quite understand how to apply this to my feed. I have new articles daily, should I set the pubDate to let say 06:00 AM today and update it every day?
- lastBuildDate: if I understand this right is the date of the latest updated item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which items should I include in RSS generation?

You should have one generic feed with all the new articles you post (for example: news). Additionally if you got your webpage split into categories, or you have some specific feeds (eg. calendar of the events) then it's good to create additional separate RSS for each one of them

> What value should I set for pubDate?  I do not quite understand how to apply this to my feed. I have new articles daily, should I set the pubDate to let say 06:00 AM today and update it every day?

Always set `pubDate` to the time when your news/articles went online. So if you have new articles daily pubDate should be a date when they were released to the public. Not random hour in the morning. Not the moment when you started writing them.

> lastBuildDate: if I understand this right is the date of the latest updated item?

`lastBuildDate` is the most recent date when any of the results was posted or modified. Usually you should skip it - especially if your lastBuildDate will be simply a most recent pubDate. It's an optional parameter.

I use lastBuildDate only for calendar RSS feeds to show when the calendar was updated (as in calendars you not only add new entries but also often edit existing).

Comment: "You should have one generic feed with all the new articles you post" -  but what does count for NEW articles? Are these only articles we post today, this week, this month? Same goes for pubDate - "Always set pubDate to the time when your news/articles went online". Which date is that? When we launched the site or what is meant here?

Comment: @PrimozRome What type of a website you have? It's static? Does it have any news or events? Cause from your questions I'd guess that you are trying to apply an RSS feed to a webpage that **shouldn't have** RSS feed.

Comment: Other than that. New articles are these that got released online most recently. Like most recent news for example. Your feed should include 10 of these, not more. Don't try to create RSS feed with "only articles you posted today" - it doesn't make any sense. As for `pubDate` - it's not a date when you launched the website. It's the date when you released the item online. So if you got your admin panel and you click "publish" for an article then the `pubDate` is a moment when you clicked publish button. If you got fully HTML website then the `pubDate` is a date when you uploaded your article.

Comment: no its a standard news portal. We publish articles daily and we have several categories. Reading at your latest comment I understand pubDate like this - pubDate should be the date of the oldest item included in the feed? For example: if I put in the feed all the articles from current week, the pubDate should be the publish date of the first article published in this week? Yay or nay?

Comment: @PrimozRome the most recent one. So if you put the feed with two articles released 20-01-2013 and 21-01-2013 then your `pubDate` of the RSS Channel will be 21-01-2013, while your `item`s will have `pubDate` 20-01-2013 and 21-01-2013 respectively (`pubDate` can be used in two contexts: [for an item](http://feed2.w3.org/docs/rss2.html#optionalChannelElements) and [for a channel](http://feed2.w3.org/docs/rss2.html#hrelementsOfLtitemgt). See http://feed2.w3.org/docs/rss2.html)

Comment: Yeah I am clear on pubDate for item element, I was asking for pubDate on a channel. So looking at your example with two articles what is then the difference between channel's pubDate and channel's lastBuildDate? According to @erwan's answer above the lastBuildDate should be the date of latest updated item, in your example 21-01-2013, the same as you say for pubDate. Still confused :).

Comment: @PrimozRome to simplify it: `pubDate` is a date of publication, `lastBuildDate` is a date of modification. So if you post a news then both pubDate and lastBuildDate will be identical. Then if you modify that news a pubDate will remain the same, while lastBuildDate will update.

Answer (score 0):

- You should put every article, but the best is to provide different feeds for different categories, even search keywords. You can build it like any dynamic page, with a querystring.
- that's not super important, you can put whatever. I don't think may feed readers use it.
- theoretically it's the date the content changed. So the date of the latest updated item should work.

Something super important, since people are going to do polling on this page (meaning a lot of requests on the page)
 - Cache it on your server
 - Serve and Etag header and/or a LastModifiedDate. That way your server can respond with just a "not modified" if the client has it in cache already.